# Ubuntu Installation(Error)

Tags: partitioning

I had Windows 10 installed in my machine, i tried to install ubuntu 18.10, however it is continuously asking me to install even after finishing the installation(Grub 2 popup comes and it has an option "try ubuntu without installing" and "install ubuntu) but i have already installed it. I am really frustrated, with this, could you please help.
Regards,
Shirish

Comment: Did you eject or remove the installation media after installing so that it can boot to the hard drive?

Comment: That's not a Grub2 popup.